# Im getting this error---> Expected a ':' after a key at 12 [character 13 line 1] from AWS Lambda while accessing the function

Tags: json, aws-lambda

1.Funcion request will be like this:

```
{
  "bucketName": "status",
  "key": "issuanceLoader3.csv",
  "source": "ftp",
  "path": "issuanceLoader3.csv",
  "processType": "ftp",
  "message": " "
}
```

2.In my code when im trying to converting the string to JSONObject it throws error from the below line of code

```
Object input = { "bucketName": "status",
  "key": "issuanceLoader3.csv",
  "source": "ftp",
  "path": "issuanceLoader3.csv",
  "processType": "ftp",
  "message": " "}
JSONObject  obj = new JSONObject(input.toString);
```

Comment: What language is that supposed to be?

Comment: its implemented in java code using spring framework

Comment: Then neither `Object input = { "bucketName": "status", ...` nor `new JSONObject(input.toString)` are valid syntax.

Comment: actually for ur referral i have hotcoded the input.but while function is called request will be called from function itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.